# Why do I need models.py for a Flask app?

Tags: postgresql, flask

As a webapp novice, I'm not sure if I need to define models.py.

I already have a working Postgres database on Heroku that I've linked up with Postico and pgAdmin. Using these GUIs, it seems I can get and post data, and make structure changes very simply.

Most tutorials seem to glaze over the details and reasoning for having a models.py. Thanks!

Comment: If you have models and want to place them in a models.py, you can do so. If you don't, don't. Flask doesn't require any specific filenames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web frameworks typically enforce or encourage a [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) patterns that structures code such that the database code is kept separate to the presentation layer.

Frameworks like django come with and are more integrated with [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) functionality which is used to implement an MVC framework. The ORM allows you to programatically interact with your database without having to write sql code. It can let you create a schema as well as interact with it by mapping programming classes to tables and objects to rows.

Flask can be distinguished from many other web frameworks, like django, in that it is considered a micro framework. It is light weight and can be extended by adding extensions. If you need the database integration then you can use it with an external ORM tool like sqlalchemy (and optionally flask-sqlalchemy extension). You can then define a sqlalchemy model, for instance, in a file called model.py or schema.py, or any other name you find appropriate.

If you only need to run one or two queries against an existing postgres database and feel you have no need for the use of an ORM, you can simply use flask with the postgres driver and write the sql yourself. It is not mandatory to have a model.

A model/ORM can be beneficial. For example if you want to recreate an integration/test instance of the database, you can instruct the ORM tool to create a new instance of the database on another host by deploying the model. A model also provides a programming abstraction to the database, which in theory should make your code more database independent (well in theory, its hard to achieve this as databases can have subtle differences), and should make your code less tied to a specific database solution. Also, it alleviates the need of writing a language within a language (sql text strings within python code).